# Not working logstash multiple kafka topic

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash, elk

logstash version is logstash-7.16.3

here is conf file

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "abc-private-vip:9092"
    topics => ["label-result","text-result"]
    group_id => "result-group"
    consumer_threads => 2
    decorate_events => true
  }
}

output {
  if [@metadata][kafka][topic] == "label-result" {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["abc-private-vip:9200"]
      index => "label-result-%{+YYYYMMdd}"
    }
  }

  if [@metadata][kafka][topic] == "text-result" {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["tcore-private-vip:9200"]
      index => "text-result-%{+YYYYMMdd}"
    }
  }
}
```

If "if [@metadata][kafka][topic] == "text-result" {...}" is removed, it works well.

What's wrong? so simple..

Comment: What does "not working if condition" mean? Can you explain what you see vs what you expect?

Comment: It means that working very well without "if [@metadata][kafka][topic] == "text-result""

Answer (score 2):

so i fixed it

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "tcore-private-vip:9092"
    topics => ["label-result","text-result"]
    group_id => "result-group"
    consumer_threads => 3
    decorate_events => "basic"
  }
}

filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => {
      "kafka-topic" => "%{[@metadata][kafka][topic]}"
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["tcore-private-vip:9200"]
    index => "%{kafka-topic}-%{+YYYYMMdd}"
  }
}


"@timestamp" => 2022-03-14T08:38:45.250Z,
        "message" => "",
       "@version" => "1",
    "kafka-topic" => "label-result"
```

metadata is exist but not pushed to elasticsearch

Comment: Good point !! The `@metadata` field doesn't make it to the output section, so you need to copy whatever you need in the filter section in order for the if condition in the output section to work.